# Why is my regex not working?

Tags: jquery, regex, url, segment

I need to match any number that comes after `/page/` in a URL.

Example URL:

```
http://example.com/something/page/2/
```

What i want out of it:

```
2
```

I wrote this, but for some reason i'm getting NULL.

```
/page/(\d)
```

Am i missing something? The regex i wrote works when testing it on [this site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but i can't get it to work in js.

When i run this:

```
console.log(url);
var mr =  url.match('/page/(\d)');
console.log(mr);
```

I get:

```
http://example.com/something/page/2/ theme.js:32
null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `var mr = url.match('/page/(\\d)');` (or a `RegExp` literal, as explained in the answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var nb = url.match(/\/page\/(\d)/)[1];
```

When you have a `/` in a regexp, it needs to be escaped.

Note that I prefer to use the `/someregexp/` notation, as a literal regexp doesn't need to be computed each time it is used.

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
/\/page\/(\d+)/
```

To match page larger than 9